# add minutes in laravel elequent not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

hi guys I wrote this code 2 month ago and now I came back and its not working I tired to trace my code and I don't understand the error:

```
$this->user->activeCode()->create([
        'code' => $this->code,
        'expired_at' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5)]);
```

with this code I add 5 minutes later to my database but its just add my current time
I tried dd :

```
dd($user->activeCode()->whereCode($code)->get('expired_at') . 'mytime ' . now());
```

response :
"[{"expired_at":"2021-03-04 09:17:23"}]mytime 2021-03-04 09:19:53"

carbon dd :

```
dd(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
```

response :

```
  date: 2021-03-04 09:27:58.581619 Asia/Tehran (+03:30)
```

(its 5 minutes later)
but when I want to save it in database that just save my current time
(I used MySQL and Laravel 6.20)

Comment: Welcome to SO ... check $fillable `expired_at` in model